# JHipster 4.5.2 - blank page

Tags: jboss, hadoop-yarn, jhipster

I have an application generated with the JHipster 4.5.2 version and I would like to launch it on a server (jboss or Tomcat) but I got a blank page (because the server side only is launched from what I understand)
When I launch mvnw and yarn start in the Command Prompt it works. 
How to launch the app in a server with client and server side working ?
Hope you understand my problem. Thanks for your help.

edit :
(got no errors when compiling. I'm using prod profile)

Jboss logs : `22:54:59,433 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:54:59.431  INFO 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.ApplicationWebXml                  : Starting ApplicationWebXml on Fred with PID 5920 (started by Freddy in D:\jboss-eap-6.4.7\bin)

22:54:59,453 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:54:59.452 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.ApplicationWebXml                  : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.7.RELEASE

22:54:59,454 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:54:59.453  INFO 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.ApplicationWebXml                  : The following profiles are active: swagger,no-liquibase,dev

22:55:02,873 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:02.873 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor

22:55:04,400 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:04.400 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Registering JVM gauges

22:55:04,432 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:04.432 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Monitoring the datasource

22:55:04,446 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:04.446 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting

22:55:05,517 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.516 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Registering CORS filter

22:55:05,934 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.932  INFO 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger

22:55:05,934 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.934 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Initializing Metrics registries

22:55:05,949 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.948 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Registering Metrics Filter

22:55:05,950 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.950 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Registering Metrics Servlet

22:55:05,962 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:05.962  INFO 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.WebConfigurer               : Web application fully configured

22:55:06,379 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:06.379 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase is disabled

22:55:12,402 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:12.401 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring GoogleConnectionFactory

22:55:12,424 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:12.423 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring FacebookConnectionFactory

22:55:12,448 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:12.448 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring TwitterConnectionFactory

22:55:17,814 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:17.813 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger

22:55:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:17.953 DEBUG 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 9 ms

22:55:19,382 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) 2017-06-03 22:55:19.381  INFO 5920 --- [read Pool -- 72] c.j.x.ApplicationWebXml                  : Started ApplicationWebXml in 23.086 seconds (JVM running for 56.264)`

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to start your app as an executable jar? This is teh simplest way and recommended by JHipster team.

Comment: Are you deploying under the root path (`/`) or a context path?  And do you have an errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Because it's asked in my enterprise. I have to generate the war and deploy it on a jboss server.

Comment: @JonRuddell I'm deploying it under a context path informed in a jboss-web.xml under WEB-INF folder. I have no error in the jboss console but got this on my browser console : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
manifest.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
 and same error for this : polyfills.bundle.js
main.bundle.js
global.bundle.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy an Angular app under a context-path, you need to update the default base href in index.html.  Inside the HTML `<head>` tag, change:

```
<base href="/" />
```

to

```
<base href="./" />
```

This will load resources from any context-path instead of expecting them to be under the root `/` path.

Comment: I followed what you said but still have the blank page. (still no error on jboss server )

Comment: so now I informed a context in my jboss-web.xml and in the html file, is it ok ?

Comment: Does your browser console show any errors?  Also make sure you are running in the `prod` profile, from above I see `swagger,no-liquibase,dev`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working with the prod profile. So I needed to update the default base href to "./myapp" and packaging with the prod profile. Thanks again.